# Seeing dam due to relations and the halachos of vests

Tags: halacha, women, time, niddah

If a woman was a "ro'eh machmis tashmish" (she saw blood after having relations), does the day that it happened go into the account of her "vestes" (the days that she will have to be concerned she may see blood and will therefore have to be separate from her husband)?

If it does, does she need to be concerned for the "oneh benonis" relative to the day she saw dam from the relations (30 days later)? Does she have to make an accounting of what the "haflagah" (the time between the last time she saw blood normally and the time now that she saw machmis tashmish) would be and be concerned for that as well?

Answer (score 1):

In Shulchan Aruch Horav Siman 187 Se'if Katan 39 it says that she has to be Choshesh for Onas Hachodesh (meaning the day of the month). As far as Haflogo she would have to see a second time Macmas Tashmish to create a Haflogo (but she does not count the Haflogo from the last regular ראייה to the first time she sees Macmas Tashmish -he explains at length why did is so). As far as Oinah Beinunus, the Alter Rebbe (also the Noda Behudah Mahadurah Kamah YD 46 says that that is the opinion of most Poskim) compares RMT to a woman who sees 'because of things happening in her body (like jumping, eating garlic, or sneezing etc.)' mentioned in Siman 189 (from Se'if 17 and on) and there he says in Se'if Katan 91 that she also has to be Choshesh for Oinah Beinunis as well.